# How do I specify that a Word TableCell shouldn't wrap using the Open XML SDK?

Tags: ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk, tablecell

I'm generating a simple Word (docx) document using the Open XML SDK. One think I'm struggling with is how to stop table cell contents from wrapping. Here's my code for generating a table cell:

```
private TableCell CreateTableCell(string text, int padding)
{
    string marginWidth = padding.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    return new TableCell(
        new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(text))),
        new TableCellProperties(
            new TableCellWidth { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Auto },
            new NoWrap(),
            new TableCellMargin(
                new LeftMargin { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = marginWidth },
                new TopMargin { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = marginWidth },
                new RightMargin { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = marginWidth },
                new BottomMargin { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = marginWidth })));
}
```

This results in the table cell width having a type of "dxa"---rather than "auto"---even though I've specified auto. And, if I replace all these "dxa" values with "auto" manually, in the xml document, then the document is as required. So, clearly my "auto" value is being ignored.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wont find text wrap for individual cells or the entire table in Word. [See here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/table-text-wrapping-in-word-2013/12b804a7-1a56-4595-a906-eb1eb539391f?msgId=726ddc23-bf66-4875-a777-86109ceb0fbb).

What you can do is; set the property of word wherein it resizes columns if the text exceeds column width.

Setting the TableCellWidth property wont help you with text wrap

Add the [Table Layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tablelayout%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property to the table which houses the cells and set its value to "auto" or you can omit the property entirely.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var cellProperties = new TableCellProperties(new NoWrap { Val = OnOffOnlyValues.On });
cell.AppendChild(cellProperties);
```